# OpenVPN Auth issue for new client

Tags: openvpn

I have Linux server with one client (Single CN) and I can connect many Linux clients perfectly.

I need to create unique CN for each client now , what I did from the server:

- Went to the dir of easy-rsa
- Run . ./vars
- Run ./build-key new-CN

I got 3 files: new-CN.crt new-CN.key & new-CN.csr

I have single client file (client-openvpn.conf), I just changed the certificates at the end of it like this
where ca.crt and ta.key are the same from the server.

```
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
ca.crt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
new-CN.crt
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
new-CN.key
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-auth>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
ta.key
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

I have this error, from the server:

```
MULTI: no free --ifconfig-pool addresses are available enp1s0f0: Unknown host
WARNING: Failed running command (--client-connect): external program exited with error status: 255
```

From the client

```
AUTH: Received control message: AUTH_FAILED
SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting
```

Please advise

Comment: Which server is providing the IP addresses in this setup? Is that server working properly? Is there a reason it cannot provide an IP address for the connection?

Comment: @music2myear the dhcp is the same, when I switch the config file to use the old certificate it works fine